# How to get the URL of all site pages in SharePoint 2010 with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I'm building a PowerShell script to get the url's for my SharePoint sites' pages (see below)

```
$siteURL = "http://mysite"
$site = new-object microsoft.sharepoint.spsite($siteURL)
$webApp = $site.webapplication
$allSites = $webApp.sites
foreach ($site in $allSites) {
    $allWebs = $site.AllWebs
    foreach ($web in $allWebs) {
        $lists = $web.Lists
        #Looking for lists of type Site Pages
        if($list.Title -eq "Site Pages") {
            # Going through all the pages in a Site Pages List
            foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
                $pageURL = XXXXXXXX
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm struggling a bit in the last nested foreach and I wonder:

- Is $list.Title -eq "Site Pages" the best way to identify a list of that "type"?
- Once I'm iterating the Site Pages list items, how can I set the &pageURL variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely use `$list.Title` to identify a list. Since "Site Pages" is a Document library, you can use extra check to identify the type of list. I reowrked your code to use Pipes. Here is an example:

```
Get-SPSite -WebApplication http://mysite -Limit All |
Select -ExpandProperty AllWebs |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary" -and $_.Title -eq "Site Pages"} |
Select -ExpandProperty Items |
Select Name, Url
```

**UPDATE**

```
$siteURL = "http://yoursite"
$site = new-object Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPSite($siteURL)
$webApp = $site.WebApplication
$allSites = $webApp.Sites
foreach ($site in $allSites) 
{
    $allWebs = $site.AllWebs
    foreach ($web in $allWebs) 
    {
        $lists = $web.Lists
        foreach($list in $lists)
        {
            #Looking for lists of type Site Pages
            if($list.Title -eq "Site Pages" -and  $list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") 
            {               
                $items = $list.Items
                # Going through all the pages in a Site Pages List
                foreach ($item in $items) 
                {                   
                    $pageURL = $item.Url
                    Write-Host $pageURL
                }
            }           
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nadeem-yousuf. I am new to PowerShell and will prefer to stick to a code without using pipes. Unless, there are a way to  use pipes in a function inside my code. Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnCasablanca, see my updated answer.

Comment: Great, I will add the $list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" condition. Answer accepted :)